401 Error when trying to delete image via REST API Woocommerce
So I am trying to delete the product along with the images via REST API but it deletes everything EXCEPT the images. I've tested it separately to delete an image but it give me this error:

{"code":"rest_cannot_delete","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to delete this post.","data":{"status":401}}

I've tried new API keys with read/write, it does not work. I'm using an admin account in my subdomain(staging site) but I can't seem to find what causes the restriction to delete images.
I'm in a standstill with this problem for days. Can anyone help me?
This is my code:
function delete_product_image($product_id) {
    $woocommerce_url = 'https://staging.website.com';
    $consumer_key = '*consumer_key*';
    $consumer_secret = '*consumer_secret*';

    $get_product_url = $woocommerce_url . '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/' . $product_id;
    error_log("URL: " . print_r($get_product_url, true));
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_product_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($consumer_key . ':' . $consumer_secret)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $product_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $product = json_decode($product_response, true);
    if (isset($product['images']) && !empty($product['images'])) {

        $image_ids = array_column($product['images'], 'id');

        foreach ($image_ids as $image_id) {
            $delete_image_url = $woocommerce_url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' . $image_id . '?force=true';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $delete_image_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($consumer_key . ':' . $consumer_secret)
            ));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $delete_response = curl_exec($ch);
            $delete_http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);

            if ($delete_http_status == 200) {
                error_log("Deleted Image with ID: $image_id");
            } else {
                error_log("Failed to delete image with ID: $image_id. Response: " . print_r($delete_response, true));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true; 
    } else {
        error_log("Product not found or no images to delete.");
        return false;
    }
}


Have you set up "WordPress REST API Authentication" plugin? I am using a plugin from miniOrange, install it and configure the REST API

@shirshak007 I've tried it just now - it still has the same issue. I'm pretty sure that they API keys are correct. I even made a new one again for it.

Just an update regarding this as I was able to resolve my issue after days of experimenting different solutions - if your API Keys don't work as intended e.g(admin access API Key but still shows unauthorized by REST) use Application Passwords instead as they work the same as API Key Authorization.
You can use this reference: Application Password Integration
If you're more of a Youtube person:
Youtube Video for Application Password Integration.
The guide there should be enough to make your way through the code. If not, feel free to ask here.
